# Anbox, cannot access '/dev/binder'

Tags: android, anbox

I have the same problem described in this thread on Super User:

https://superuser.com/questions/1590707/ls-cannot-access-dev-binder-no-such-file-or-directory-in-anbox

Anyway, when I run INSTALL.sh as suggested by Yadu, I get the following:

[CODE]Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

```
Building module:
cleaning build area...
make -j4 KERNELRELEASE=5.8.0-38-generic all KERNEL_SRC=/lib/modules/5.8.0-38-generic/build....(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for anbox-ashmem: 1 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.0-38-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/anbox-ashmem/1/build/make.log for more information.

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
make -j4 KERNELRELEASE=5.8.0-38-generic all KERNEL_SRC=/lib/modules/5.8.0-38-generic/build....(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for anbox-binder: 1 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.0-38-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/anbox-binder/1/build/make.log for more information.
binder_linux          192512  0
ashmem_linux           20480  0
ls: impossibile accedere a '/dev/binder': File o directory non esistente
crw------- 1 root root 10, 58 gen 17 17:32 /dev/ashmem[/CODE]
```

Any help? I hope that here I can find someone who can help, because on Super User no one cared about my problem.  I'm on Kubuntu 20.10.